# Server is assigned IP by GUID rather than MAC address in DHCP

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, dhcp, dell-poweredge

I recently installed 8 new Dell PowerEdge c6220 II servers with dual 10G ports with CentOS 6. Each server has a DHCP reservation configured from a Microsoft 2003 DHCP server.

I am using a Bootutil program by Intel that enables PXE booting with these NIC's as required based on a solution provided by Dell support 2 years ago. For some strange reason, 5 of the servers are getting a *DIFFERENT* IP address during the PXE boot process, but when the OS boots, the reserved IP address is correctly obtained.

I have searched the DHCP server for the IP that it obtained during PXE boot and noticed that in the "Assigned IPs" pane, under the unique identifier column there is a GUID number rather than a MAC address like it should be.

I deleted the entry and tried re-adding the reservation, but nothing works. 
For example: a host with a reservation for 10.0.0.10, obtains another IP address during PXE boot. But after the OS boots, it obtains 10.0.0.10

I would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1) A Wireshark capture will help to see if the PXE DHCP requests use the expected MAC addresses or not.

2) The PXE DHCP request and the following DHCP request include different parameters.
Please check that your reservation rule is not overlapped for some other rule taking precedence in the case of a PXE DHCP request.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
1) Found the packet with wireshark , doesn't say much to me except for the fact that it uses the guid as uUid . the source IP during pxe boot is 0.0.0.0 , src port bootpc(68) , same as dst port. next server is 0.0.0.0 (which is not what I set) , the obtained IP address is the wrong one , Client identifier Client Identifier (UUID): 4c4c4544-005a-4410-804e-b2c04f573032 (which is what I see in the DHCP's assigned address uid column .
2) What could it overlap with ? there's obviously no other reservation for this mac/ip address. What else could it be?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) the packet must include the source MAC address; You have to see if that MAC address matches the one you use when you made the IP reserve. 2) That's something that you have to see with your DHCP Server documentation; just keep in mind that a PXE DHCP request and a regular DHCP request are different animals.

Comment: Yep it matches. But still unable to see something on the dhcp server's side

Comment: mmhh. Does your reservation includes "Supported types=both" ? You can also try reserving by GUID instead

Comment: Yeah it's set as both , I tried by GUID and it didn't work:( any other ideas?

Comment: try again reserving by GUID; read here http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/460278-dhcp-reservation-needs-guid-not-mac  and see if it applies to your case

Comment: Tried upgrading bios..didn't help . the funny part is that some of those Dell servers do work. Identical to each other but only some work.

Comment: re-read the link; the guy solved the problem "downgrading" the BIOS; if that fails you should be able to filter by GUID like the guy did.

Comment: Does it make sense to downgrade the bios even if I have an identical server that arrived at the same day , same bios and BMC version which DOES get the reservation IP at PXE boot?

Comment: do the same servers have the exactly the same NICs? do those NICs have the same firmware? on board NICs have their firmware included with the BIOS firmware... Here your problem is the PXE DHCP request and that is performed by the NIC PXE firmware.

Comment: Hi Pat ,Just checked it , it's the same Firmware of pxe ,everything is the same . I'm really lost :\ can figure out what is causing this .

Comment: They cannot be the same; try to see the difference with wireshark of the DHCPDISCOVERY/DHCPREQUEST packages sent by both PCs the one that works and the one that doesn't. There must be a difference at DHCP level and that is handled by the PXE NIC firmware.